# Twitter API request error while using node.js

Tags: node.js, http, twitter, terminal

I am trying to make a request to the Twitter API and respond with the JSON.

This is my code.

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var url = require('url');

app.get('/twwets/:username', function(req, response) {
    var username = req.params.username;

    options = {
        protocol: "http:",
        host: 'api.twitter.com',
        pathname: '/1/statuses/user_timeline.json',
        query: { screen_name: username, count: 10}
    }

    var twitterUrl = url.format(options);
    request(twitterUrl).pipe(response);
}).listen(8080);
```

And this is what I get when I run `node app.js` in my terminal:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'require'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/geosh/node.js_practice/express_practice/app.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I need to know what do I do wrong.

[My code may seem useless, but it's just for educational purposes. Please excuse any mistake.]

EDIT: I still get the same error after I saved and run the code in my shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo;

```
var request = require('require');
```

should most likely be

```
var request = require('request');
```

EDIT: You're also missing `express`, I suspect you'll want to add these lines;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

...and `npm install request express` to get the modules installed.

Comment: Thank you. I will look more carefully on my code before asking a question.

LATER EDIT: I still get the same error.

Comment: @GeorgeNetu You'll need to `npm install request`. You're also missing a definition for `app` which may be `express`?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following links may use

http://expressjs.com/

For Twitter Authentication

http://passportjs.org/